# Sata III hard drives not recognized by ECS motherboard caused data corruption of hard drives

Tags: hard-disk, desktop, sata, hardware-compatibility, ide

I connected two new sata hard drives to my ECS G31T-M9 motherboard. They are mechanical SATA III hdd's 500 GB and 1 TB respectively.

Issues started to happen with this 500 GB drive first, the motherboard eventually wouldn't detect it, so an immediate solution appeared by swapping the sata ports between drives, this solved the problem during an arbitrary time period, running fron one week to months, this problem sometimes appered after power surges but sure not the only cause.

Symptoms evolved rapidly affecting both drives and reaching to the point where one or both partitions were instantaneosuly unmounted by the OS without apparent reason and almost every mount attempt will be followed by an authomatical system unmount action.

Note to this is that the problem seems to only affect the sata drives as I also have an Ide drive connected and never seemed to have any problem.

The system running arch linux and all partitions contained ext4 file systems, so according to fsck this wasn't related to any errors inside the file systems because all error reports if any were unconsistent with this forced unmounts.

This reached to a point where all the sata hdds won't load on the bios no matter what I tried, this final issue risen all the red flags, so I disconected all the sata drives and connected them to a different motherboard, a biostar P4m89-m7b.

The biostar immediately recognized the drives so I spend some days backing up and recovering the data. I succesfully recovered all the files and nodes from the 500 GB drive but the partition was corrupted, the main superblock was missing and e/s errors were continuosly reported to system logs though luckly ddrescue only detected one error on the drive containing only 512 KB or so.

I momentanously suspended all the tests in this drive untill I check that indeed all my files are there and the 1 GB drive is still up for testing.

All that happened burnt out all my confidence on the first motherboard, the ecs one, but I'm still wandering what could have caused all this trouble.

Could it be that the PSU is failing? it's a generic 500W power supply and I attached to it just three hdd's and some external periferals, including speakers and printer.

BTW if it's related to the PSU why I had no troubles with the remaining ide hard drive?

It's a very intriguing mystery i search for answers so I preciate any comment.

Edit: this was the output in journalctl during unmounts blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 15488728 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 8 prio class 0

Edit2: A quick inspection on the logs start reporting problems on 20 september (2020)  at 16:56:59 on both drives simultaneously, logging starts on september 9, I'm horrible at following dates so I suppose that previous events from that date were trimmed and overwritten.

Complete log entries for both drives are the following:

- 1 TB drive: https://cloudvyzor.com/logpad/?query&database=sandbox-88e449dee9b24ad5b0d3aa4054833df0
- 500 GB drive: https://cloudvyzor.com/logpad/?query&database=sandbox-bd50684d63a559a1930f1424d7597f7b

Unrepeated log entries for both drives are the following:

- 1 TB drive: https://cloudvyzor.com/logpad/?query&database=sandbox-6718aced5b022e2261450da3fda8cbf3
- 500 GB drive: https://cloudvyzor.com/logpad/?query&database=sandbox-d729f9a2dad82e8020aa0fc350964105

Full events from september 20:

- full: https://cloudvyzor.com/logpad/?query&database=sandbox-2188b0d89a8ea4579709a4c6e3ce434b
- unique: https://cloudvyzor.com/logpad/?query&database=sandbox-a60a4149659a2e9deffc6f373aa6e46e

Comment: How many disk discontrollers are there? On older boards, you may still need to set the jumpers on the sata drives. Or remove the ide drive and see what happens - but I'm guessing the system is on the ide drive. Also, look at the output of "dmesg" on a clean boot with all the drives connected. If there's a power problem you should see something in dmesg - as well possible reasons why the sata drives are dropping off.

Comment: I'm guessing the system is on the ide drive

Right guess, you-re right.

All that I remember were the continous E/S errors for both SATA drives.

At the moment, all the SATA drives are unplugged until I'm able to store my files at a safer location. On monday or tuesday I will purchase a new hard drive to be this location and I can start testing on the failing drives.

Comment: How many disk discontrollers are there?



How can I tell? Which command lines I need to issue in order to this?

Comment: this was the output in journalctl during unmounts blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 15488728 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 8 prio class 0

Comment: I added the full logs at the body

Comment: I only glanced at first 10-15 lines for the first file - you have hardware problems - the kernel and udev are both complaining from the beginning.about sdc The problem may not be the drives - it may be the controller.  So yes, you're goting to have I/O errors. I'd get rid of the LVM, plugin 1 drive - the 500 GB and then after you reboot do a dmesg. There should be no kernel errors on sdc. Assuming you have a SATA IDE controllers, type "lspci | grep SATA".

Comment: 00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)

Comment: then the motherboard is faulty?

Comment: Not necessarily. There may be setting in BIOS which allows you to switch between IDE and SATA - its in the IDE mode. Ideally, there would a setting to allow you run both IDE and SATA.  However, you may still have to add jumpers to the SATA drives - and more importantly, I can't predict whether or not flipping the BIOS setting will corrupt your IDE hard drive. Also, it's possible SATAIII drives are to large for the controller. Instead of messing with the BIOS, I would look insider the computer and see if it has a PCIExpress slot.  If it does, then I would buy a SATA PCIExpress controller.

Comment: It does have PCIExpress slot based on image from Amazon for the motherboard G31T-M9 (V1.0) . Which OS are running? And would you post "cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -E 'model name|cpu MHz'.

Comment: Should I clarify that there aren't any SATA drives attached to my computer at the moment, because as I already said I removed them all so there's only one ide drive which contains the system:

Comment: NAME   FSTYPE FSVER LABEL         UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                                   
├─sda1 ext4   1.0   arch-pantheon 29cc484e-4d42-44cb-8748-8b9df848fb5e    4,6G    81% /
├─sda2 swap   1     swap          fa62f295-575f-4a4e-9067-cd8770a939cd                [SWAP]
└─sda3 ext3   1.0                 678f97a0-33d8-48ff-b4e2-2b1a16754184  155,6M    94% /home
sdb                                                                                   
└─sdb1 vfat   FAT32 VIDEOS        9115-C838

Comment: Ah and a usb pendrive. May be that's why the controlled is in ide mode?? or should it be in sata mode anyways?

I'm using arch linux and my cpu is a dual core:

model name : Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5300  @ 2.60GHz
cpu MHz  : 2348.452
model name : Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5300  @ 2.60GHz
cpu MHz  : 2190.092

Anyway this old motherboard deserves a nice retirement right now, may be I'll buy the sata controller or a raid controller to use it only as a NAS.

Comment: Also do you mean that the bios is bad configured? 
Ok, now i know that I can pin a SATA  drive to limit data transfer rate, I never worried for this because as I asked the seller, "Sata drives don't require pins". Can I pin a SATA drive that was unpinned?

Comment: I have a similar machine - an old Dell Optilex - primarily for backups. If you're not worried about high perfformance, I purchased a 2 port  USB3 PCIexpress card, a StarTech USB3  2-drive bay RAID enclosure, and then installed  2-4TB drives. WIth the enclosure dip switches, I was able to by-pass the RAID and mount the drives seperately. Another possibility. It completely bypasses the BIOS and disk controller - and I didn't have to mess with things that were working.

Comment: Regarding the IDE disk controller, it's probably IDE interface pretending to be a SATA interface. This  implies SATA version is old and that version of SATA may not work at all with SATAIII. I don't know what pinning means. By jumpers, I mean setting the addat ss on the IDE controller. Also, IDE drives are typiclly much smaller then current SATA drives.

Comment: This implies SATA version is old and that version of SATA may not work at all with SATAIII 

It's surely implementing SATA II which has forwards compatibility with SATA III, though may be not forward so much. Ahh you mean jumpering the motherboard.

Comment: Why don't you use RAID? Specially RAID1 which mirrors the data. I'm considering using RAID1 so I always have a backup though that I'm worried about complexity and portability.

Comment: Actually, I do use RAID - but not the hardware RAID in the enclosure. I prefer to use Linux RAID to the mirror drives.

Comment: No, the jumpers are on the disk drive sets the address of the drive on the controller, e.g., device 0, device 1, etc.

Comment: What can you tell me about the state of my disks? I already rescued around 300 GB from the 500 GB drive, I guess those are all the files it contains, but how to be sure? I have many backups of the partition, as disk, as partition and as image of the partition. The original has bad superblock and many inode errors but the image files seem totally fine, they're mounted on a loop without problems, even fsck says they're clean. Can you give me any clue?

Comment: I can't tell you much. The controller maps out bad blocks.. And whether or not fsck will see errors on a loopback interface depends upon how you made the disk image. The test would be to see if you can use the data on the loopback interface.

Comment: I used plain ddrescue to clone the patition to an image file.

¿What do you men with use? I have already been able to read the data on the loopback and copy it to a safe place, checked some files and they're ok. Did you mean to try to write on the loopback?

Comment: ddrescue ignores the bad blocks. If the so called bad backs are actually bad, then you have holes in files. Or maybe the holes are articfacts of the IDE controller. You won't now untill you purchase a SATA!!! controller and plug in the drivers. You can buy one for around $45.

Comment: mmm, the next thing to fail on that mobo is the pci bus and I'm not taiking that risk again.